# FabricJS - disable layer index changing when object is selected

Tags: selection, z-index, fabricjs, bringtofront

I've a problem with my FabricJS app. By default, the object layer in fabricjs jumps to the top when I select it.

I want to disable this option so that the index of the active element not changing. It's possible ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You just need to set the `preserveObjectStacking` options as shown in the below code when setting up the canvas.

```js
var fabricCanvas = new fabric.Canvas("t", { preserveObjectStacking: true });

fabricCanvas
  .add(new fabric.Rect({
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    fill: "green"
  }))
  .add(new fabric.Rect({
    top: 50,
    left: 50,
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    fill: "red"
  }))
  .add(new fabric.Rect({
    top: 100,
    left: 100,
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    fill: "blue"
  }))
  .renderAll();
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="t" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.6.3/fabric.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This option I was looking for. Thank You very much !