# fabric.js how to control selcted element to be not on top

Tags: fabricjs

I use fabric.js to develop a editer.

[image: init canvas had a text and a rect]

[image: when selected the text]

I hava a text and a rect, the text is bottom, when I selected it, I hope it also is bottom...please watch images attached.

May I?

How the current selected object is drawn, a new object? in a coord object?

Comment: check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39149655/3551786)

Comment: try replicating it in jsfiddle so other devs can edit it.